# ASIHTTPRequest - best practice to cancel multiple request?

Tags: ios, asihttprequest

I've got a for-loop which sends multiple ASIHTTPRequests:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
     [request setDelegate:self]; 
     [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestDone:)];
     [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestWentWrong:)];
}
```

To safely handle the delegate being deallocated before the requests have finished, I'd like to cancel those requests; how can I achieve that? Store all the requests in a NSMutableArray? Or can I achieve that using a queue? Thanks a lot for your help!

Stefan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution depends on your architecture and application needs - eg. Do you have multiple http requests only some of which you might want to cancel?

Here's one solution - it'll cancel and remove the delegate of **all** in progress requests that have been assigned to the default queue:

```
for (ASIHTTPRequest *req in ASIHTTPRequest.sharedQueue.operations)
{
    [req cancel];
    [req setDelegate:nil];
}
[queue setDelegate:nil];
```

Comment: looks good; does that mean I don't have to use the request as ivar and put your code in the dealloc-method?

Comment: Yes, probably - but be careful. You probably want to do it in viewDidDisappear, as dealloc could be called after another view has started a new http request. An ivar or a queue per view controller can make a lot of sense, but these are architecture decisions that only you can make (there's nowhere near enough detail in your question to suggestion which is the right/best approach for your app).

Comment: I know, my question is very general; but I think you helped me a lot; I nevertheless put it in my dealloc; probably I set the userInfo-dictionary on the requests, so I only cancel the requests which belong to that viewcontroller. Thanks!